# Typescript type guard for Type[keyof Type] function parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Sorry for the confusing title.

I'm trying to use a lookup type similar to the `setProperty` example in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types

The lookup type is correctly checked when calling the function but can't be used inside the function. I tried working around this with a type guard, but this doesn't seem to work.

Example:

```
interface Entity {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function handleProperty<K extends keyof Entity>(e: Entity, k: K, v: Entity[K]): void {
  if (k === 'age') {
    //console.log(v + 2); // Error, v is not asserted as number
    console.log((v as number) + 2); // Good
  }
  console.log(v);
}

let x: Entity = {name: 'foo', age: 10 }

//handleProperty(x, 'name', 10); // Error
handleProperty(x, 'name', 'bar'); // Good
// handleProperty(x, 'age', 'bar'); // Error
handleProperty(x, 'age', 20); // Good
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsFsAcEsA2BTAJqA7vALgC1ALQEDO2ATvAMbYByAroouLspQNbEBQ8AdtsmQBmAQ0rJQAUT44AnqADenUKB7DoyAFyhSFHgHMA3EtDC9mlXWgAjAUYC%20nTimygAHlqnZZoALwLV6loA5IKQkEEANCZmWgCMAAygDpyCdDzU8JA8oLjCPKgoAApkkLAC2DIAPADSoMiu-PnEoGzIMpCCktIVAHwAFOaeslFsWtVRAG4e3TIA2tUAugCUWhOQ8OiKyvCdfWy%20Pn5BpshBSwrGyhO%20oNcAVKAATAagIJJkJWSToPDNPJAuYTEYjlNAmP6WGxkYwOZSULLESAoAB0iEgej6EyW9kcIFy%20SKJTKZAqfVcUSCAVOUQS2NeYAkH0g0PxBWQxVK5RkZIpVMioCCVmEZDOLzeAHEwqhOG9WYTOSTueSBSd%20YLhaL6e9Ppw5eyiVyeSqzPzHvE6RKpY4gA)

Is there any way to make typescript figure this out, without hard-coding a type assertion: `(v as number)`? At that point in the code, the compiler should be able to infer that `v` is a number.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Mutating function arguments, considered a bad practice

Comment: @captain-yossarian I agree. I'll edit the question to reflect my intention. I want to use the argument using the type that I know it to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that the compiler cannot narrow the type parameter `K` by checking the value of `k` inside the implementation of `handleProperty()`.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085).)  It doesn't even try.  Technically, the compiler is correct not to do so, because `K extends "name" | "age"` does not mean that `K` is either `"name"` or `"age"`.  It *could* be the full union `"name" | "age"`, in which case, you cannot assume that checking `k` has an implication for `K` and thus `T[K]`:

```
handleProperty(x, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "name" : "age", "bar"); // accepted!
```

Here you can see that the `k` parameter is of type `"name" | "age"`, and so that's what `K` is inferred to be.  Thus the `v` parameter is allowed to be of type `string | number`.  So the error inside the implication is correct: `k` might be `"age"` and `v` might still be a `string`.  This completely defeats the purpose of your function and is definitely not your intended use case, but it's a possibility the compiler is worried about.

Really what you'd like to say is that *either* `K extends "name"` *or* `K extends "age"`, or something like `K extends_one_of ("name", "age")`, (see [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808),) but there is currently no way to represent that.  So generics don't really give you the handle you're trying to turn.

Of course you could just not worry about someone calling `handleProperty()` with the full union, but you'll need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation like `v as number`.

---

If you want to actually constrain callers to the intended use cases, you can use a union of [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) instead of generics:

```
type KV = { [K in keyof Entity]: [k: K, v: Entity[K]] }[keyof Entity]
// type KV = [k: "name", v: string] | [k: "age", v: number];

function handleProperty(e: Entity, ...[k, v]: KV): void {
  // impl
}

handleProperty(x, 'name', 10); // Error
handleProperty(x, 'name', 'bar'); // Good
handleProperty(x, 'age', 'bar'); // Error
handleProperty(x, 'age', 20); // Good
handleProperty(x, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "name" : "age", "bar"); // Error
```

You can see that the type `KV` is a union of tuples (created by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `Entity` to a type whose properties are such tuples and then immediately [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the union of those properties) and that `handleProperty()` accepts that as its last two arguments.

Great, right?  Well unfortunately that does not solve the problem inside the implementation:

```
function handleProperty(e: Entity, ...[k, v]: KV): void {
  if (k === 'age') {
    console.log(v + 2); // still error!
  }
  console.log(v);
}
```

This is due to lack of support for what I've been calling *correlated union types* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)).   The compiler sees the type of the destructured `k` as `"name" | "age"` and the type of the destructured `v` as `string | number`.  Those types are correct, but are not the full story.  By destructuring the rest argument, the compiler has forgotten that the type of the first element is *correlated* to the type of the second element.

---

So, to get around *that*, you can just not destructure the rest argument, or at least not until you check its first element.  For example:

```
function handleProperty(e: Entity, ...kv: KV): void {
  if (kv[0] === 'age') {
    console.log(kv[1] + 2) // no error, finally!
    // if you want k and v separate
    const [k, v] = kv;
    console.log(v + 2) // also no error
  }
  console.log(kv[1]);
}
```

Here we are leaving the rest tuple as a single array value `kv`.  The compiler sees this as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) and when you check `kv[0]` (the former `k`) the compiler will, *finally*, narrow the type of `kv` for you so that `kv[1]` will also be narrowed.  It's ugly using `kv[0]` and `kv[1]`, and while you could partially mitigate this by destructuring after the check of `kv[0]`, it's still not great.

---

So there you are, a fully type safe (or at least closer to type safe) implementation of `handleProperty()`.  Is it worth it?  Probably not.  In practice I find that it's usually just better to write idiomatic JavaScript along with a type assertion to quiet the compiler warnings, like you've done in the first place.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-PEx7fr+-4YohN6bveO4kmSFL5NStL0kyrIcj6PJ8tGHJvuKn6weCjhJukXipgha4EfmBqFsWzxsAGapVlsOxttqhyiYs8S2qczYQdceztjOXYIj2RwzIssS2v21wgjwkBjueUSCLwwiMDIE5JHWsm6QpTa7i2qm3NODwuKW-qKR0MxGO2nmzt2SJ9v8RlgCZZlkBZVk2XZU4aXO2lyfpi6OLxQEbg+u77lER6sae7FZUhMi5U+6iQaK0Egj+kB-qV-GoRBj5QVhbHnrhK58VmFVof8mGsfVf7ddefXEaSuDkpSFGgHSDLMmynKBPRUZmH6wqiixMECOOnBAA)

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed and informative explanation! Added a thumbs up on the correlated union types issue.

Comment: for future reader, now it works with `if (k === 'age') {` (tested on typescript 5.1.6)