# Discriminating between callback union types with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm converting some code to TS and want to implement this interface

```js
let handler = new Handler()
  .on("data", (content) => /*something*/)
  .on("finished", (content) => /*something else*/);
```

but I've run into problems discriminating between callback types.
Putting the callbacks into discriminating unions doesn't work because they have different signatures.
This is what I've got so far:

```js
interface Content {
    x: string,
    y: string,
}

type EventType = "data" | "error" | "finished";

type DataCallback = (content: string) => void;
type ErrorCallback = (content: string) => void;
type FinishedCallback = (content: Content) => void;

type EventCallback = DataCallback | ErrorCallback | FinishedCallback;

class Handler {
    ondata: DataCallback;
    onerror: ErrorCallback;
    onfinished: FinishedCallback;

    on(event: EventType, callback: EventCallback) {
        if (event === "data") this.ondata = callback;
        else if (event === "error") this.onerror = callback;
        else if (event === "finished") this.onfinished = callback;
        else console.error(`Unhandled event: ${event}`);

        return this;
    }
}
```

But this gives the following error(s):

```
      TS2322: Type 'EventCallback' is not assignable to type 'DataCallback'.
  Type 'FinishedCallback' is not assignable to type 'DataCallback'.
    Types of parameters 'content' and 'content' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Content'.
```

which totally makes sense.

Is this interface impossible to implement in Typescript?

One option is to change the interface to

```js
onData(callback: DataCallback) { this.ondata = callback; }
```

etc, but I was hoping that I could keep the same interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same pattern as [`window.addEventListener`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18307).

You first make a map from your event types to the callback types they expect:

```js
interface EventCallbacks {
    "data": DataCallback,
    "error": ErrorCallback,
    "content": ContentCallback,
}
```

And then you type your `.on` method as

```js
on<E extends keyof EventMap>(event: E, callback: EventCallbacks[E]): Handler;
```

Now when writing `on("data", ...)` typescript will know that the second argument must be a `DataCallback`

Comment: Thanks! That helps, but when assigning `this.ondata = callback` iI still get the same error.

Comment: Works with `this.ondata = callback as DataCallback`. Are there any disadvantages with this?

Comment: @Anton I think the `as` assertion should be safe here, yes, but I of course might be overlooking something! Making assertions bypasses typescript's type system, and therefore if you make them, safety is no longer guaranteed by TS. Of course TS is limited (this all seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65831204/11308378), and sometimes it's the only sensible option.

Comment: The answer I linked in my previous comment actually illustrates this situation very well with `Math.random`: what should typescript expect as the second argument if you start with `on(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "data" : "content", ...)`. It cannot determine the callback type at compile time, and thus the implementation of `on` can't actually know the true `callback` type either

Comment: Turns out that `on<E extends keyof EventCallbacks>(event: E, callback: EventCallbacks[E]) { this._events[event] = callback; }` works without assertions.