# Property `key` does not exist on type 'Type[T]'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

When I check if the `index` is "name", why it doesn't work. The typeScript should catch this, knowing that if the `index` is equal to "name", then `value` is the `name` object.

```js
interface Person {
  name: {
    text: string
    id: number
  };
  age: number;
}

const person: Person = {
  name: {
    text: 'me', 
    id: 789
  }, 
  age: 30
};

const changePerson = <T extends keyof Person>(index:T, value: Person[T]): void => {

  if  (index === 'name') {
    value.text = 'he'
  }

  person[index] = value;
  
}

// OK
changePerson("name", { text: 'you', id: 123});

// Compilation error
changePerson("name", 32);
```

TS Playground: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBc+xppkAHmLRmFKAOb0PAAmtEAFcKAI2i8AvgG5ecLjTKiJUOUSnFiCHO2QAHTDlroo2XAF46JMpSWEbjCC1oByKq4A0yXqQG0AdgAOAE5pb3lFWgBmAAZiWS0iHRA9BAALOBBFU3NkKwAeABVkZ0gQfgxkAGsIAE8sGDQjEAA+AApQfmdqIu8ANzgAG2ElXJwAbSKAXQBKWn6sAXzW615gJuROiud8iytXcg9Z6wZkQZGIADpmMHzkV3SIV2kk0kMzSa7nafuL0fUpASSQA9CDkAB5ADS2ky2Qg4xA7QAREcIMjvHhkLc3A1hF5kP5kABGABM0Sks3UxDByAAwlgKPpgEM4GBgDhSlAoFgoLCsjkWii0RjkNFSVTiEAIADyAGltGkMhBRiBWgAiA4w3x4RzFZwuOAYfgwDBwTE%20PyCZBRAAsACYoiSiVJpupiP9kABhLAUfTAAZwMDAHBFKBQLBQMHpTJNWHw3wk6nEIA)

My guess is that when generic types are used with union types, TS is unable to narrow it as I would expect.

But I am very confused about the specific details. Please give me a detailed explanation. Thank you all.

Comment: This is really similar to the question given in end of [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36050). But the cornerstone issue seems to be [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).

Comment: One possible workaround is explicit type assertion: `if (index === 'name') {(value as Person['name']).text = 'he'}`.

Comment: See [the answer to the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65831204/2887218) for more information.  If I translate the code there to this question, it yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WKkxKW).